# Converting row level details to column values in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have data in the below format stored as dataframe in R,

[image]

Now i need the output as follows,

[image]

Can anyone provide me the code as how i can transform the data in R for the above mentioned dataset and the bring the output as per the image uploaded.

Regards,

Mohan

Comment: Please try to post example data as text, not images; it makes it easier to provide answers.

Comment: Sure @neilfws...

Comment: Please modify your title, it's very uninformative as it stands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `recast` to do the data transformation

```
library(reshape2)
recast(df1, id.var = "Company", Company ~ value, length)
#   Company CRV diesel Grande Petrol
#1   Honda   1      0      0      1
#2    Tata   0      1      1      0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(Company = c("Honda", "Tata"), model = c("CRV", "Grande"),
           version = c("Petrol", "diesel"), stringsAsFactors= FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially tabulating by column, it seems, so you should be able to also use `table`, with no additional packages.

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(df1[-1], function(x) table(df1[[1]], x)))
##       CRV Grande diesel Petrol
## Honda   1      0      0      1
## Tata    0      1      1      0
```

This way, relevant columns are also grouped together rather than being sorted alphabetically.